# Вывести каждую функцию которая используется в приложении

Tags: python, python-3.x

Переделал много функций, некоторые из них стали работать не корректно. Как мне отследить каждую вызванную функцию в данный момент? (Писать принт внутри каждой функции не хочется..)

---

Дополню:
Функции выполняют роль клика по экрану, где-то клики игнорируется что и вызывает у меня ряд проблем. Хотелось бы знать что у нас сейчас отрабатывает в данный момент чтобы можно было это легко отследить.

Comment: Покажите минимально воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: Который воспроизводит не корректность работы функции.

Comment: @Александр код большой. Я нашел проблемное место. У меня без ошибок игнорируется функция click из pyatogui. Почитал вроде как из-за асинхронности. Попробую использовать ооп, надеюсь поможет (логика - не, не слышал). Но вопрос остаётся открытом. Как без боли в режиме реального времени отследить функции которые на данный момент вызвались.

Comment: @Incover использовать дебаг-режим

Comment: @ClarkDevlin не понимаю. Кроме как дебажить через print я не знаю. Код работает без ошибок try нигде не используется.

Comment: @Incover в пайчарме есть точки останова, с помощью них

Comment: Логирование добавьте. Вроде есть простые способы с помощью декораторов.